# Trouble getting mouse position with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

I have an onmouseover event attached to an anchor. I'm trying to get the mouse position within that event handler, but the coordinates are coming back as undefined. Here's what I'm trying:

```
<a onmouseover="SetTopLeft(this);"...

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetTopLeft(obj)
    {
        alert("width/height = " + obj.pageX + "/" + obj.pageY);
    }
</script>
```

I've also tried:

```
alert("width/height = " + $(obj).pageX + "/" + $(obj).pageY);
```

...with the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert("width/height = " + $(obj).offset().left + "/" + 
($(obj).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop());
```

Comment: Offset doesn't give me the position relative to the whole browser window which is what I need.

Comment: Hmmm...like magic. I will use this, but I'm still curious why jQuery's documented method doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Search a little on Google first...

Docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 
})
```

If you need the position of the object, you can use:

```
$(selector).position()
```

Comment: I did search on Google first. That's where I got my code. This is supposed to work for any event, but it's not.